# React Router Dom - How to redirect between dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, connected-react-router

```
class Recommended extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {}

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        path="/recommended/category/:categoryId"
                        component={SceneRecommendedCategory}
                        render={() => {
                            return <SceneRecommendedCategory />;
                        }}
                    />
                    <Route exact path="/recommended" component={SceneRecommendedList} />
                </Switch>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

```
handleChangeCategory = categoryId => {
        const { history } = this.props;
        history.push(`/recommended/category/${categoryId}`);
    }
```

```
<Link to={`/recommended/category/${category.id}`}>A</Link>
```

Hi, so my problem is i can not redirect between **/recommended/category/:categoryId**. Url was changed from **/recommended/category/1** to **/recommended/category/2**, but reactjs was not rendered, i can tell there is nothing change.
Please help me out.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are specifying both component and render on the Route component?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yes, that...using both `component` **and** `render`... immediately stuck out to me. NHSon, can you share the component code for `SceneRecommendedCategory`? You may need to use `componentDidUpdate` or some other prop check on the route param `categoryId` to check when it changes from `1` to `2`.